# Divide or multiply each element of a List<int> every time a new number is added

Tags: c#, list, integer, operators

Input: One number at a time.

Output: The entered list in which every even number is divided by 2 and every odd number is multiplied by 3.

The steps will be something like this:

1. input 4 and get as output [2]
2. input 8 and get as output [1,4]
3. input 9 and get as output [3,2,27]

Here's my current code:

```cs
List<int> nummerListe = new List<int>();

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie die Zahlen ein : ");
    string eingabe = Console.ReadLine();
    int nummer = int.Parse(eingabe);

    Console.WriteLine("Die Zahlen sind : ");
    nummerListe.Add(nummer);
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= nummerListe.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nummerListe[i]);
        Console.Write(" , ");
        if (nummer % 2 == 0)
        {
            nummer /= 2;
            Console.WriteLine(nummerListe[0] = nummer);
        }
        else
        {
            nummer *= 3;
            Console.WriteLine(nummerListe[0]=nummer);
        }
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine("  ");
}
```

Comment: Why does 8 output two numbers? Why does 9 output 3 numbers?

Comment: The first two lines contradict the bullet points. Can you please [edit] the question and clarify?

Comment: Ah, I think I get what you mean now but shouldn't the third input (9) produce "[3,2,**27**]"?

Comment: @Llama i guess it's because every time you enter a new number, all operations are perfomed again on all numbers that were saved earlier. It doesn't explain, why it's [3, 2, 9] and not [3, 2, 27] though.

Comment: because i want to do this with a lot of numbers that user writes.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(nummerListe[0]=nummer)` seems *very wrong*

Comment: No, I'm not asking about your motivation. The desired logic of your application isn't clear to me. Your description says _"The entered list in which every even number is divided by 2 and every odd number is multiplied by 3."_ - therefore if we enter 4 we should get 2, if we input 8 we should get 4, and if we input 9 we should get 27.  Your example paints a different picture: we instead see that inputting 4 returns 2 (that's right), inputting 8 somehow returns 1 AND 4, and inputting 9 somehow returns 3, 2, AND 9. This is completely different to what you have described.

Comment: Please can you explain in human terms, pen-to-paper style, what you want to do with an input to produce the output in your example.

Comment: yes but i was falsch with 9, but what i get is not what i want.

Comment: i get 1 because 2 is even and should again /2 .

Comment: Do you mean that the inputs are related and not isolated inputs?

Comment: @Llama it means that each input is added to the list, and the operations are processed for the whole list each time, which his code is almost already doing (excepted for the few bugs in it)

Comment: Somehow, the fact that OP is reading each input with `Console.ReadLine()` is contradictory with the statement "*Input: **comma-separated** number list*" - it's more like "new-line separated"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- You're starting the loop at 1, instead of 0, ignoring the first element.
- You're changing `nummer` instead of the actual element in the list.
- You're always assigning the value of `nummer` to the first element of the list: `nummerListe[0] = nummer`.

Try something like this:

```
List<int> nummerListe = new List<int>();

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie die Zahlen ein : "); // Enter the number
    string eingabe = Console.ReadLine();
    int nummer = int.Parse(eingabe);  // Consider using int.TryParse() instead.
    nummerListe.Add(nummer);

    for (int i = 0; i < nummerListe.Count; i++)
    {
        if (nummerListe[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            nummerListe[i] /= 2;
        }
        else
        {
            nummerListe[i] *= 3;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Die Zahlen sind : "); // Numbers
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", nummerListe));
}
```

Comment: oh my God . thank you so much , now i got my problems

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to learn that C# Lists are 0-base indexed, which means that your loop should look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nummerListe.Count; i++)
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 1; i <= nummerListe.Count; i++)
```

Then you should double-check this:

```
Console.WriteLine(nummerListe[0] = nummer);
```

Because:
1 - You'd have to replace `0` with `i` (`nummerListe[i] = nummer`)
2 - You wouldn't want to print the result of the assignment (which you currently do).

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> nummerListe = new List<int>();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie die Zahlen ein : ");
            string eingabe = Console.ReadLine();
            int nummer = int.Parse(eingabe);
            Console.WriteLine("Die Zahlen sind : ");
            nummerListe.Add(nummer);
            nummerListe = nummerListe.Select(n => (n % 2 == 0) ? n / 2 : n * 3).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", nummerListe));
        }
    }
}
```

You can try it [online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dcNPwd).